# Numpy symmetric matrix becomes asymmetric when I applied min-max scaling

Tags: python, numpy, minmax, symmetric, standardized

I have a symmetric matrix (1877 x 1877), here is the [matrix file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5i73euwmpzgy94x/data.csv?dl=0). I try to standardize the values between 0-1. After I apply this method, the matrix is no longer symmetric. Any help is appreciated.

```
print((dist.transpose() == dist).all()) # this prints 'True'
def sci_minmax(X):
    minmax_scale = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    return minmax_scale.fit_transform(X)
sci_dist_scaled = sci_minmax(dist)
(sci_dist_scaled.transpose() == sci_dist_scaled).all() # this print 'False'

sci_dist_scaled.dtype, dist.dtype # (dtype('float64'), dtype('float64'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing-scaler) description the minmaxscaler appears to work column-by-column, so, naturally, you can't expect it to preserve symmetry.

What's best to do in your case depends a bit on what you are trying to achieve, really. If having the values between 0 and 1 is all you require you can rescale by hand:

```
 mn, mx = dist.min(), dist.max()
 dist01 = (dist - mn) / (mx - mn)
```

but depending on your ultimate problem this may be too simplistic...

Comment: Yes, you are right, i didnt realize the minmax scaler applies to feature columns.. thanks!